# How to replace a sequence of commands by a single command in linux?

Tags: shell, command-line, alias

How can we replace the following commands

```
netstat -nat | awk '{print $6}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
```

by our special command like this:

```
ab1
```

my mean is I want to use my command

```
ab1
```

instead of

```
netstat -nat | awk '{print $6}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use an alias, or install an executable script in some directory included in your $PATH

Assuming bash, a "global" alias could be defined in `/etc/bash.bashrc` (or `~/.bashrc` if a single user need this alias to be defined). Assuming ksh, it would be in `/etc/ksh.kshrc` (or `~/.kshrc`). The alias definition can be done adding a line such as:

```
alias ab1='netstat -nat | awk "{print \$6}" | sort | uniq -c | sort -n'
```

Comment: i think in linux we have special command and this command work is replace comand with other command , i forgoted this command , i want to reload my mind with my needed answer

Comment: this file is empty /etc/bash.bashrc m we should create it ?

Comment: you may not be using bash. What does `echo $SHELL` tells you?

Comment: Unless you want to force the alias onto every user of the system, don't use /etc/bashrc; use ~/.bashrc

Comment: echo $SHELL /bin/bash

Comment: @radolf Then you should be able to create it. Meanwhile, the best solution remains adding an executable script to some directory listed in your $PATH (see `echo $PATH`, prefer `/usr/local/bin` if available).

Comment: i am using your command in last of nano ~/.bashrc file and i reload network via service network reload , but i cannot get answer -bash: ab1: command not found

Comment: There is no need to reload your network after having edited your aliases. Although you'll need to run something like `exec bash` to re-read your configuration

Comment: Or just `. ~/.bashrc`

Comment: . ~/.bashrc
-bash: alias: } | cut -d: -f1 | sort | uniq -c | sort -n: not found

Comment: @SYN can you please help me bout this problem?

Comment: There's a typo in your alias definition. Are you sure you've properly copied the sample from my answer? I can confirm it works.

Answer (score 1):

```
alias ab1='netstat -nat | awk '\''{print $6}'\'' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n'
```

I would recommend placing that in your `~/.bashrc` file.

Comment: this can't work. Single quotes won't escape as expected.

Comment: Good point; I'm not at a shell to test; I think you need:  '\'' for each `'`

Comment: -bash: ab1: command not found

Answer (score 1):

put the below code in your .bashrc file.

```
ab1(){
netstat -nat | awk '{print $6}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
}
```

and source the bashrc file

```
. ~/.bashrc
```

now type ab1 in your terminal